# Adding textbox value to alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

New at JavaScript and I'm trying to write an alert box that not only says Thank You For Visiting when you click the Enter button but also says the name entered into the text box.  I have the box saying Thank you For visiting but can't figure out how to make it so that it says Thank You For Visiting Name.

This is what I have so far

```
<title>JS-Colors</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function salutation () {
        var goodbye= document.getElementById('name').Value;
        if (confirm("Thank You For Visiting") == true){
            goodbye="Thank You For Visiting";
        } 

    }
</script>
```

and this is the html part of it

```
First Name:<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="button" value="Enter" button onclick="salutation ()"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Element.value` returns a `string` which is `primitive` and hence `immutable`..

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by your code and the whole if statement part, but according to your description this is what you want:

```
function salutation() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  confirm("Thank You For Visiting " + name);
}
```

[Try it out here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXxoKz)

Comment: so was I, that's why I was asking.  Thanks but I finally figured it out after figuring out how to use alert.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this is what you are asking for?

```
function salutation() {
  var val = document.getElementById('name').value; //value of the input.
  if (confirm("Thank you for visiting "+val+".")) {
     //do something if user has clicked the ok button on the confirm.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out, I was looking for this

```
function FirstName(){
var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
var name=alert('Thank You For Visiting ' + name);
}
```

HTML

```
First Name:<input type="text" id="name"/>
<input type="button" value="Enter" button onclick="FirstName ()"/>
```